# (CSS) user-modify. Редактирование по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, css

В шаблоне используется свойство **user-modify** для всех тегов **span**.

```
span {
  display: block;
 -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
 -moz-user-modify: read-write;
  user-modify: read-write;
}
```

Как реализовать редактирование на странице по нажатию на кнопку (ВКЛ/ВЫКЛ)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переключать класс родителю и установить зависимость свойств для редактирования от переключаемого класса.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.editor').classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
.editor.active span {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px dotted;
 -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
 -moz-user-modify: read-write;
  user-modify: read-write;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle modifying</button>
<br><br>
<div class=editor>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
  <span>asdasd</span>
</div>
```